# HTML labels with ocamlgraph

Tags: ocaml, graphviz, dot

Is it possible to make a graph like [this one](http://www.graphviz.org/content/psg) with ocamlgraph? HTML labels have to be delimited with `<>` instead of `""` and I don't see any mention of this functionality in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can *parse* this kind of dot nodes: the documentation for the [Dot_ast](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/doc/Dot_ast.html) module of OCamlgraph has a `Html of string` case of the `id` type for this. It seems like they cannot *print* this kind of dot files, as the `` `Label `` node of the [Dot attributes](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/doc/Graphviz.CommonAttributes.html) only handles direct strings.

If you need this feature, you could consider implementing it yourself (just change the files `graphviz.ml` and `graphviz.mli`), I'm sure the authors would be glad to have some contribution.